# How to handle or check User Control postback in Parent page?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a checkbox in my user control. How do I disable my parent control's event when user control's checkbox's CheckedChanged event was triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable events from it ASP.Net Life Cycle.

However, you can check inside each Event whether the postback is triggered by Parent or User Control.

If you want to check which control fire event inside **Parent** page -

```
public partial class Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            string id = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) && id.Contains("WebUserControl11"))
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

If you want to check whether this event is fired by one of my control inside **UserControl** -

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack) // *** This IsPostBack is not same as Parent's IsPostBack ***
        {

        }
    }

    protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {

        }
    }
}
```